# only submit the page is ajax was successful

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending an email in jQuery and PHP, i need to tell the page to submit if the ajax was successful and don't submit if not.
I have tried to place the return values in the success and error attributes, but that did not work, so i want to see if i could set the form to not send by returning false but if it was successful letting it submit the page for some server side work.

In the example below i have tried to set a variable and used a conditional to read it. I get an error message because the value does not seem to get passed globally, so when the conditional reads sendMe, it says it is undefined.

Is there a way to do this correctly?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        var sendMe = 'true';
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Error: Message could not be sent');
    }
});

if (sendMe == 'true'){
    //Submit the page...                    
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wait! What?! You realy want a string for using it as a boolean?

Comment: The answers below are a better way of doing what you are trying to do but as a note to your issue with the "sendMe" variable not being available. This is only being set within the success function, if you want it to be global in the page then it would help doing something like "window.sendMe = true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create a `sendMe()` function, and call that function from `success:`
That should do the trick.

The reason your code does not work is because the javascript is not waiting for the ajax call to come back, right after the ajax call it evaluates sendMe which at that point is still false.

You could consider doing this call synchronously of course to prevent that, but I am not sure that is the right way to go. ( `async : false` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 )

Comment: Thanks, i did hear about the async:false, but i thought i would try and do it corrcetly :)

Answer (score 2):

When is your conditional
     if(sendMe == 'true') ...
ever getting called?

make a little function like this:

```
    function sendMe(){
    // whatever your form's id is, put it in place of myForm
    $("#myForm").submit();
    return true;
    }
```

and in your ajax success block call the function

Comment: Agreed; identical to what tom already said, but it doesn't cost me any money to upvote two answers. ;-)

Comment: This is good, but it seems to create a loop. I am trying to submit a from in ExpressionEngine, so i don't know if $("#myForm").submit();
creates to loop mixing in with EE

Comment: not sure why you think it creates a loop. Of course, you would want your form to be validated before submitting it, so maybe you have other form elements that also need to be checked. I don't know what your form looks like.

Comment: I don't think it creates a loop i know because i tested it, it kept looping through the success function

Answer (score 0):

Try using this setup:

```
var form = this;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        form.submit(); // submit form, bypassing jQuery events
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Error: Message could not be sent');
    }
});
return false; // prevent submit
```

By returning false after the ajax request, we prevent the submit, then we directly submit the form bypassing all of jQuery's submit handlers using `form.submit();`

Comment: This is good, but still creates a loop and the form never submits. I'm using ExpressionEngine, so i don't know if the jQuery from submit is mixing with the EE fucntion and it gets stuck?

Comment: make sure `form` in this case is not a jQuery object, but the actual form element.

Answer (score 0):

Set the form to go through a validator method on submit event:

`<form onSubmit='return checkForm();'>
</form>`

In this method - `checkForm()` - perform your ajax post normally. If the ajax post returns as 'success' proceed with the submit else use `return false;` to cancel submit and notify the user accordingly.

Comment: Inline event handlers are a bit old-school. I wouldn't use the onSubmit, myself, especially since they're using jQuery and there are easy methods for binding.

Comment: That is exactly what he is currently doing in principle. It just doesn't work because the ajax request doesn't complete before the return.

Comment: @GregPettit I do not consider them as such, however as you have said jQuery does offer easier methods such as `.bind()` to bind an event to a particular function.

Comment: @KevinB so in theory the ajax post still is recognizing the post as successful, right?

Comment: Thanks guys, you make a good point of me maybe not doing it correctly, is there a way i should have done, eg. using .bind?

Comment: @JamesGatt Basically, the form returns before the ajax requests's complete or done callbacks get fired, meaning before you validate the value.

Comment: @zizther the send.php file does it echo anything back ?

Comment: send.php sends an email and the form submission will add an entry into ExpressionEngine. So what i am trying to do is send an email and then submit the form to add then entry. The email is sent, just the page does not submit, i have used some of the examples mentioned, but they create a loop, not sure if this si to do with EE?

Comment: @zizther what you need to add in send.php - you need to check whether the operations you have set to carry out have indeed been carried out - if they were you should echo back to the client a 'true' flag, otherwise a 'false' flag.

Comment: @zizther what I would do is I would just echo back a json array should the send.php executed successfully, such as the following: `echo json_encode(array('success' => true));` . Then i would just check from the ajax post whether the success variable retrieved from the 'send.php' is set to true. If it is then it means that everything was carried out successfully

Comment: @JamesGatt this helped! The only problem i have not is getting the form to submit i have tried using .submit, but this creates some weird loop. At the moment i return false after the AJAX function, could i set this to true? Or would the email never send that way?

Comment: @zizther the return false statement should be inserted where and IF an error has occurred. If the ajax post was succesful you do not return false. So your return false should be removed from after the ajax post - otherwise the form would never submit being successful or failed in the ajax post

Comment: @JamesGatt If there are errors it does return false, i put return false after the ajax so the page did not send without sending the email. When the form submits it goes to another template and is managed server side (adding an entry to the DB), but the ajax is sending an email. I could put the email script on the success template but duplicate emails are sent if the user refreshes the page, and i cannot see a way of stopping the duplicates happening

Comment: @JamesGatt Thanks for your help. Becuase of the way i had it setup i had to use async : false. Next time though i'll do it correctly